# Why is onActivityResult() not getting executed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter, onactivityresult

I'm an experienced java programmer taking my first steps in Android development. My problem is simple, my `onActivityResult()` is not getting executed in the main activity. Here is what I did.

In the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewScreen.class);

startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_OK);
```

And I did override the `onActivityResult` method in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("Debug", "Received");
}
```

In `NewScreen` Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NewScreen.this, MainActivity.class);

this.setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

Log.d("Debug", "Setting the Result");

finish();
```

My Manifest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="NewScreen"></activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NewScreen activity, try using the default (parameter-less) constructor for the Intent...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

Log.d("Debug", "Setting the Result");

finish();
```

**EDIT:** Also the 'request code' you send to the activity might be better as some value other than `RESULT_OK`, e.g...

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
```

Answer (score 5):

You used `RESULT_OK` as request code. The value of `RESULT_OK` is negative (`-1` actually). That's why you didn't receive result from `NewScreen` activity. If you look into documentation for [`requestCode` argument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), it says:

> `requestCode`     If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

So, you should define your non-negative request code and use it for `startActivityForResult`. Here is the example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    static final int REQUEST_CODE = 13;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         //...             

         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewScreen.class);
         startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the key to this problem is stated in the [documentation for `startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)): "Using a negative requestCode is the same as calling startActivity(Intent) (the activity is not launched as a sub-activity)."

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that its not getting called. Try printing out the result code. If its zero it could mean that the result is being cancelled giving you the illusion that the method is infact doing nothing.

Comment: How did you solve it? I get zero for my result code and null for intent. Thanks